# Ошибка kill в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Задача состоит в следующем

Написать скрипт который
завершает все процессы, начавшиеся более чем N секунд назад.

```
find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user olo -type d -mmin +1 -exec basename {} \; \
| xargs ps | grep page.py | awk '{ print $1 }' | sudo xargs kill
```

это то что я смог найти

Но почему отказывается работать kill? И как его починить?

[image: скрипт]
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91717/discussion-on-question-by-balir--kill--ubuntu).